# Unhandled exception at 0x52f9e470 in project1.exe : 0xC000001D : Illegal instruction

Tags: opencv

i am trying to detect an object using opencv in c++ but i am getting an error :
Unhandled exception at 0x52f9e470 in project1.exe : 0xC000001D : Illegal instruction.

using windows 7 32 bit,opencv 2.4.3,visual studio (c++) 2010 and my code is :

```
   #include <opencv\cv.h>
   #include <opencv\highgui.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <assert.h>
   #include <math.h>
   #include <float.h>
    #include <limits.h>
   #include <time.h>
   #include <ctype.h>


      // Create a string that contains the exact cascade name
     // Contains the trained classifer for detecting hand
    const char *cascade_name="D:/31dec12/hand.xml";

    //The function detects the hand from input frame and draws a rectangle around the         detected portion of the frame
    void detect_and_draw( IplImage* img )
    {

    // Create memory for calculations
    static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;

    // Create a new Haar classifier
    static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;

   // Sets the scale with which the rectangle is drawn with
   int scale = 1;

   // Create two points to represent the hand locations
   CvPoint pt1, pt2;

    // Looping variable
    int i; 

    // Load the HaarClassifierCascade
    cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad( cascade_name, 0, 0, 0 );

    // Check whether the cascade has loaded successfully. Else report and error and       quit
    if( !cascade )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );
     return;
     }

    // Allocate the memory storage
    storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    // Create a new named window with title: result
     cvNamedWindow( "result", 1 );

    // Clear the memory storage which was used before
    cvClearMemStorage( storage );

    // Find whether the cascade is loaded, to find the hands. If yes, then:
    if( cascade )
    {

       // There can be more than one hand in an image. So create a growable sequence of hands.
      // Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
      CvSeq* hands = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage,
                                        1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                        cvSize(40, 40) );

      // Loop the number of hands found.
      for( i = 0; i < (hands ? hands->total : 0); i++ )
      {
        // Create a new rectangle for drawing the hand
         CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( hands, i );

          // Find the dimensions of the hand,and scale it if necessary
          pt1.x = r->x*scale;
         pt2.x = (r->x+r->width)*scale;
         pt1.y = r->y*scale;
         pt2.y = (r->y+r->height)*scale;

         // Draw the rectangle in the input image
         cvRectangle( img, pt1, pt2, CV_RGB(230,20,232), 3, 8, 0 );
       }
     }

     // Show the image in the window named "result"
      cvShowImage( "result", img );


    }


    // A Simple Camera Capture Framework
     int main()
    {

     // Gets the input video stream from camera
     CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );

     // Checks if the input stream is obtained
     if( !capture ) 
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
    getchar();
    return -1;
  }

   // Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
 while( 1 )
  {

    // Get one frame
     IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

    // Cecks if a frame is obtained
    if( !frame )
    {
    fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
    getchar();
    break;
   }

  // Flips the frame into mirror image 
  cvFlip(frame,frame,1);

   // Call the function to detect and draw the hand positions
    detect_and_draw(frame);

    //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
   //remove higher bits using AND operator
    if( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) 
    break;
   }

   // Release the capture device housekeeping
    cvReleaseCapture( &capture );

   return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

What kind of cpu are you using?  Last time I had the error: 0xC000001D : Illegal instruction was related to the SSE instruction used in the code. Some new SSE instruction are not implemented at AMD processors e.g. So you can fix this by rebuilding opencv without SSE support.

Comment: i am using core i3 second generation processor windows 7 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem when using cv::Mat(...)

The same exception throw at 
`size_t esz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(_type), esz1 = CV_ELEM_SIZE1(_type);`

Not so sure why but after changing Visual C++ Project floating point model from precise to fast, the problem solve.