# C++ - unable to start correctly (0xc000001d) - openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to run an OpenCV 2.3.1 application through Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. I have generated the release exe file correctly, and it works fine on my windows 8 - 64 bits. In addition I would like to run it on Win XP, so I have tested it on a Win XP SP3 and it ran ok. However, when I try to run this exe on Win XP SP2, which is the target O.S. for my app, I get the following message:

> unable to start correctly (0xc000001d). Click Accept to finish the
>   application

Any idea please?

Answer (score 4):

Finally I have solved the issue: 0xC000001D: Illegal instruction, which was related to the SSE instruction used in the code. Some new SSE instruction are not implemented at some different CPU; In this case, the problem was related with my CPU: "via nehemiah". I tested the software again on a XP SP2 with CPU Intel and it worked perfectly. Finally I have to say that there is a great post which was helpful in order to fix the issue:

[Unhandled exception at 0x52f9e470 in project1.exe : 0xC000001D : Illegal instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401024/unhandled-exception-at-0x52f9e470-in-project1-exe-0xc000001d-illegal-instruc)

Comment: If you need to support ancient processor, specify `/arch:IA32` in MSVC compiler options to [disable modern CPU instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx).